# Searching the first few characters of every word within a string in C#

Tags: c#, wordsearch

I am new to programming languages. I have a requirement where I have to return a record based on a search string.

For example, take the following three records and a search string of "Cal":

1. University of California
2. Pascal Institute
3. California University

I've tried `String.Contains`, but all three are returned. If I use `String.StartsWith`, I get only record #3. My requirement is to return #1 and #3 in the result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use string.Contains, and drop the second one. If you're looking for the beginning of any word in the record, you need to `Split()` each record, and do a StartsWith on each element in the split array.

Comment: Look into string.split(), then loop through each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this for simplicity:

```
if(str.StartsWith("Cal") || str.Contains(" Cal")){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, I'd recommend using the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). Check out [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx). Something like:

```
string myString = "University of California";
bool included = myString.Split(' ').Any(w => w.StartsWith("Cal"));
```

`Split` divides `myString` at the space characters and returns an array of strings. `Any` works on the array, returning true if any of the strings starts with `"Cal"`.

If you don't want to or can't use `Any`, then you'll have to manually loop through the words.

```
string myString = "University of California";
bool included = false;

foreach (string word in myString.Split(' '))
{
    if (word.StartsWith("Cal"))
    {
        included = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are newbies with Lambda expressions? I like this answer, but I'm not sure how someone New to Programming would follow it.

Comment: It will probably confuse them a good amount I would guess. Personally I would avoid Lambdas with newbies just to keep the learning curve from being too steep, although the proposed solution is definitely a good one.

Comment: I say it's never too early to start! But I included a for-each example just in case.

Comment: I would recommend to start with the most readable technology available. SO why not with linq?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
foreach(var str in stringInQuestion.Split(' '))
{
  if(str.StartsWith("Cal"))
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: A good answer, just make sure that you don't have a string that would satisfy this `if` statement more than once, like "California Institute of Calliopes"  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expressions to find the matches.  Here is an example

```
    //array of strings to check
    String[] strs = {"University of California", "Pascal Institute", "California University"};
    //create the regular expression to look for 
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"Cal\w*");
    //create a list to hold the matches
    List<String> myMatches = new List<String>();
    //loop through the strings
    foreach (String s in strs)
    {   //check for a match
        if (regex.Match(s).Success)
        {   //add to the list
            myMatches.Add(s);
        }
    }

    //loop through the list and present the matches one at a time in a message box
    foreach (String matchItem in myMatches)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(matchItem + " was a match");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string univOfCal = "University of California";
        string pascalInst = "Pascal Institute";
        string calUniv = "California University";

        string[] arrayofStrings = new string[] 
        {
        univOfCal, pascalInst, calUniv
        };

        string wordToMatch = "Cal";
        foreach (string i in arrayofStrings)
        {

            if (i.Contains(wordToMatch)){

             Console.Write(i + "\n");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You should provide something in addition to code, specifically please provide some information about what your code is actually doing and why it works.  The OP has stated he/she is new programming, so a block of code with no comments on how it works it not going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = new List<string> { "University of California", "Pascal Institute", "California University" };
var matches = strings.Where(s => s.Split(' ').Any(x => x.StartsWith("Cal")));

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Output:

```
University of California
California University
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a good use case for regular expressions.

```
string[] words = 
{ 
    "University of California",
    "Pascal Institute",
    "California University"
}

var expr = @"\bcal";
var opts = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
var matches = words.Where(x => 
    Regex.IsMatch(x, expr, opts)).ToArray();
```

The "\b" matches any word boundary (punctuation, space, etc...).